# Is there any way to store a null value in an array of integers?

Tags: c++, arrays, null, integer

I am trying to create an array of integers but I do not want all values of that array to be of type integer. I want to store `null` in some places and integers in other places. eg.

```
arr[] = {50, 20, null, 30, null, null, 60}
```

In java, I am aware that you can declare the array is Integer and store `null` (`Integer[] arr`). Is there any way I can do the same for C++?

Comment: You can't store value with different types in array.But you can store pointers, and leave the null value with nullptr pointer. Or store std::any into array.

Comment: No.   You can deem that some particular value represents "null data", but recognising that null value requires logic specific to your program.    I suppose you could use an array of `std::optional<int>` but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Comment: Do the same as in java, create an Integer class

Answer (score 2):

You can't store values types with different types in the array(Actually there is no java's null in C++ ). But you can store pointers, and leave the null value with nullptr pointer. Or store std::any/std::optional into array with c++17.

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 7> ar1 = {std::make_unique<int>(50),
                                             std::make_unique<int>(20),
                                             nullptr,
                                             std::make_unique<int>(30),
                                             {},
                                             {},
                                             std::make_unique<int>(60)};
  std::array<std::any, 7> ar2 = {50, 20, {}, 30, {}, {}, 60};
  std::array<std::optional<int>, 7> ar3 = {50, 20, {}, 30, {}, {}, 60};  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the case of `std::unique_ptr<int>` it makes sense to define user defined literal, so we can write something like `50_up` instead of `std::make_unique<int>(50)`

Comment: @sklott Greate to learn that, I haven't seen any literal for make_unique

Comment: User defined literal can return any type generated from usual literals. What I meant is something like `std::unique_ptr<int> operator "" _up(int v) {return std::make_unique(v);}`